# Check if data has a comma, if so display error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I need to be able to filter my dataset by saying:
if the commitments field has a comma, then display an error for that row in the results field.

Current code:

```
WHERE [Commitments] NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

Which is essentially just passing through data with numerical values. Some of the data have commas. For those fields that have commas, I want to be able to have it show an error. I was thinking of having this filter in possibly the SQL level.

[image: Example]

An example of what is on the right. As you can see, when its filtering, if it is all numerical numbers, I want it to display it as is. However if it consists of any commas, I want it to display and error instead.

Comment: What is your desired output?  Would outputting a status column be satisfactory?

Comment: I have updated my post with an image. I would like it to display in the initial column. So have it show numerical data in the initial column, and or if it consists of any commas, have it display an error instead. Hope this answers your question

Comment: @youngj You must clarify your question and add some Data examples and some code. Then could be easy to help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following answer assumes that if you see one or more commas in the commitments column, you want to print an error.  If commas could be present there, it means that the column type must be text.  We can try using the following `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT
    col1,
    -- other columns
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',', Commitments) > 0
         THEN 'Error'
         ELSE Commitments END AS status
FROM yourTable
```

Again this assumes that `Commitments` is text.  If it is already numeric, then there cannot be any commas in there to begin with.

Comment: What is the meaning of this comment?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen is saying you can add his CASE statement onto the end of your SQL to get your desired result

Comment: @YoungJ Just add my `CASE` expression to your select list.